# Replace the text inside the td without touching the other child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
<td class="cant_formula numeric">
    0.007
    <input type="hidden" value="0.015" class="cant_formula"/>
</td>
```

I want to replace the text inside it, I tried these ways:

`$('td.cant_formula.numeric').contents().first()[0].textContent='fsdfwffwwfwf`';

but it doest not work!!

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gp5gmmgx/

Can you help me, What Im doing wrong??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this https://jsfiddle.net/gp5gmmgx/2/

```
$('td.cant_formula.numeric').contents()
    .filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3; //Node.TEXT_NODE
    })
    .get(0).nodeValue = 'test';
```

1. `table` element is required else `td` elements aren't selected;
2. about selecting text nodes read https://stackoverflow.com/a/298758/3349900.

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle doesn't seem to work with that version of jQuery.  (I can't even get a simple alert to work.)

Upgrade to at least v 1.9.1

Also, `td` elements must be within `tr` elements, which must be within a `table`.

https://jsfiddle.net/0rnLa9j1/

Comment: This is also wrong, OP wants to grab the text node, ignoring the child elements

Comment: I want to change only the text element

Comment: @SterlingArcher, I don't understand.  This should do just that.

Comment: Your fiddle still grabs the asterisks, whereas OP wants JUST the text

Comment: Right, my fiddle fixed his fiddle, but his post and his fiddle don't match.

Comment: Then this isn't an answer because it doesn't solve the issue, only fixes issues with the original fiddle?

Comment: @juanpscotto, put it in a table, and it does work:  https://jsfiddle.net/0rnLa9j1/

Comment: Not a problem.  Amazing that jsFiddle is broken with jQuery < 1.9.1.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$('td.cant_formula.numeric').text("text");
```

Actually after testing, this replaces all the contents of the td not just the text.  I should have listened to my gut and double checked before answering, apologies!